# At the centroid does the gradient becomes zero?

Tags: differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Suppose we have a **smooth differentiable planar curve** given as $F(x,y)=0$. Suppose that the **centroid** of the **curve** $F=0$ is $F(x_0,y_0)$.

> My question is:-
> $$\nabla F(x_0,y_0)=0$$
> That is, does the gradient of $F$ becomes **zero** at $(x_0,y_0)$?

Now some **examples** supporting this statement are **circles and ellipses**.

I would be grateful if anyone proves the **statement** or gives a **counter example**.
Also I welcome anyone who would like to **generalise** this statement in any direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you recall what is the centroid of the curve?

Comment: For parametric smooth curve it probably is $\int_0 ^1 \vec{a}(s)ds$ where $s$ is arc length parameterizing  $\vec{a}$, if the total length of curve is 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $$F(x,y) = x^4 - 4 x^3 + 2 x^2 y^2 - 4 x y^2 + 16 x + y^4 - 16.$$

The graph of $F(x,y) = 0$ is a circle of radius $2$ centered at the origin,
so its centroid is $(x_0,y_0) = (0,0).$

But

$$ \nabla F(x,y) = (4 (x^3 - 3 x^2 + x y^2 - y^2 + 4), 4 y (x^2 - 2 x + y^2)),$$

which is not zero at $(x,y)=(0,0).$

(To obtain this function, I treated the coordinates $x,y$
as the real and imaginary parts of a complex number $z = x+iy,$
applied the Möbius transformation $z \mapsto (z+1)/(z-1),$
separated the result into real and imaginary parts $x'$ and $y'$,
and applied the circle formula $x'^2 + y'^2 = 4.$
This produced a circle with center at $(-1,0)$, so I changed
$x \to x-1$ to translate the circle's center to the origin,
then expanded the polynomial.
I was hoping that the Möbius transformation, while it mapped a circle to a circle,
would distort things enough to put the zero gradient off-center,
and this turned out to be a good guess.)

Comment: Thanks for such an excellent answer and also sharing the root of the intuition how you came up with the solution. I plugged in the equation in Wolfram and then gave graph as the circle you mentioned and also other forms of y in terms of X two of which were "y is complex for all x in R" now my question in continuation to this is this why we are getting the non zero directional derivatives and if for all x in some open set all roots of y is real them can we guarantee my statement in question is true.

Comment: And as another continuation to the last comment, is this weaker version of my given statement in the question true, **i.e. there exist a vector, directional derivative along which is zero?** In your example along y axis direction the directional derivative is clearly zero.

Comment: The second question is trivially true, because no matter what direction the gradient is, you can just take the direction perpendicular to that and then the directional derivative in that direction will be zero. If you are only concerned about the coordinate axis directions, we could transform the equation by a $45$-degree rotation of the $x$ and $y$ coordinates in order to get a gradient whose $x$ and $y$ components were both non-zero.

Comment: From what you say, Wolfram shows you something a little different than what I see when I give the equation to Wolfram Alpha. I see four solutions for $y$ in terms of $x,$ of which two are zero at $x = 2$ and non-zero imaginary for all other real $x$ and two are real for $-2\leq x\leq 2$ and non-zero imaginary for all other real $x$. I didn't see anything "complex for all $x$ in R" if "complex" signifies "not real".

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4%E2%88%924x%5E3%2B2x%5E2y%5E2%E2%88%924x*y%5E2%2B16x%2By%5E4%3D16+plot+%28x%2Cy%29

Comment: If you restrict your investigation to equations that are quadratic in $x$ and $y,$ then the only curves with well-defined centroids are circles and ellipses and the gradient is always zero at the centroid. But that seems like an oversimplification of the question. More generally $F$ should not even necessarily be a polynomial nor should we necessarily be able to come up with solutions for $y$ for each $x.$ I only chose what I chose because it was still a circle and I know its centroid.

Comment: Under the solutions sections the third and fourth one shows $y=\sqrt{-(x-2)^2}$

Comment: Okay and what about the weaker statement that's there is a vector along which the directional derivative is zero  at the centroid?

Comment: Ah, I thought you were quoting it when you wrote "complex for all $x$ in $R$." What you actually have is complex for all $x\neq 2$ in $R,$ not the same thing.

Comment: Yes that was my mistake in that comment and any idea about the weaker statement or how to approach or any counter example hopefully doing with only the basis vectors completes all the other generic cases.

Comment: I meant directional derivative of F not gradient of F actually in previous statements.

Comment: Okay yes that's true too for if gradient is non zero,the perpendicular vector to gradient vector in that subspace where gradient is, along that direction, the directional derivative is zero.